# Why LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap uses both LinkedHashMap and HashMap?

Tags: java, spring, collections

I'm looking at the structure of LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap (spring framework 5.0.5.RELEASE). I'm curious why LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap uses both LinkedHashMap and HashMap, and why not just use LinkedHashMap like this?

```
   private final LinkedHashMap<String, V> targetMap;

   public V get(Object key) {
      if (key instanceof String) {
         return this.targetMap.get(convertKey((String) key));
      }
      return null;
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private final LinkedHashMap<String, V> targetMap;

private final HashMap<String, String> caseInsensitiveKeys;
```

In this case `targetMap` contains real-case string to your object, and `caseInsensitiveKeys` contains mapping your key in lower case to your real-case key.

It allows to show you real-case keys when you are doing for-each iteration, but at the same time it allows you to have case insensitivity.

So let say, following code:

```
LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap<Object> map = new LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap<>();
map.put("MyCustomObject", new Object());
```

will put `"MyCustomObject" -> new Object()` in `targetMap`, and `"mycustomobject" -> "MyCustomObject"` in `caseInsensitiveKeys`. And now if you try to print all objects from your `map` it will print it as you added and not changed keys. You can't archive it without second map.

Comment: You could achieve this with a single map, e.g. by wrapping the keys into objects with case insensitive equality and unwrapping them in iterators, but in the end, you have to decide for a particular implementation strategy.